# Get Parent Document by using has-child in Elastic Search

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, nest, elasticsearch-5

I am new to elastic search and I am trying to search through the child document and fetch the parent document, but i am getting no documents in the result Please help me out. Thanks in advance. Nest code is mentioned below:

```
 var child = _client.Search<T>(s => s
                  .From(0)
                  .Size(20)
                 .Query(q => q
                 .HasChild<T>(c => c
                 .Type("child")
                 .MinChildren(1)
                 .Query(s => s.Wildcard(w => w.Field("pa_description1").Value($"*{"2"}*")))
                   )));
```

Comment: for haschild you need to pass child model ex. HasChild<childclass>

Comment: @jaspreechahal, I tried, but it did not worked, still 0 documents

Comment: can you add your mapping,  models(parent and child) and a sample document to recreate it